# Glyphicon wrench with caret for dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I was just wondering if anyone knows how to create a clickable (caret beside) glyphicon (wrench) with a nice dropdown menu to select from? Any insights would be great!

Current Code for glyphicon wrench:

```
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>
         <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
```

When I click on the caret, I do not seem to get a dropdown menu. Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 4):

> Am I missing something obvious here?

You have missed the `.dropdown` wrapper which establishes a new containing block for the `absolute`ly positioned dropdown menu.

Therefore the dropdown menu is now positioned relative to the initial containing block. You could wrap the elements by a `<div>` having `.dropdown` class as follows:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/zogiv/1/edit)**

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>
     <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- items here... -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>A `position` property with a value other than `static` establishes a new containing block. Twitter Bootstrap applies `position: relative` to the `.dropdown` by default.</sub>